# using same namespace php, Call to undefined function

Tags: php, class, namespaces, undefined

using same namespace php

I have this files in the same folder :

*OtherFunctions.php*

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
$Tble = NULL;

function SetTble($tble) {
  global $Tble;
  $Tble = $tble;
}

function GetTble() {
  global $Tble;
  return $Tble;
}

function Funct0($Str0, $Str1) {
  return $Str0 == $Str1;
}

function Funct1($Arg) {
  return "The Value is ".$Arg;
}
//... from 0 to 16
function Funct16($Arg) {
  return "The Value is ".$Arg;
}
?>
```

**How to call all functions contained in this file?**

In one class File *SubClass.php* I have this:

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
class SubClass {
  public $CArg = "";
}
?>
```

In other class File *LeadClass.php*
I have this:

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
use \Pack\sp\SubClass;
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
class LeadClass {
  public function __construct($Name) {
    echo("_._");
    $NewSC = new SubClass();
    $NewSC->CArg = $Name;
    SetTble($Name);
    echo("ini:".GetTble().":end");
  }
}
?>
```

I want call all function in one instruction of OtherFunctions.php File, but I don't kno how to do it....

**I trying to replicate this message in other code**
Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetTble() in C:...\LeadClass.php on line 10

**But, I'm obtaining blank page**

**EDIT**

Was added the line:

```
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
```

And was replaced the line:

```
require_once("SubClass.php");
```

by the line:

```
use \Pack\sp\SubClass;
```

in *LeadClass.php* File.

**But, I'm obtaining blank page**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the next line

```
namespace Pack\sp;
use \Pack\sp\SubClass; // <--- add this
```

Also I think you should put the functios of the OtherFunctions file into a new class link

namespace Pack\sp;

```
class OtherFunctions{
  // your current code goes here
}
```

After that you need to extend the SubClass whit the OtherFunctios class

```
namespace Pack\sp;
use Pack\sp\OtherFunctions;
class SubClass extends OtherFunctions {
  public $CArg = "";
}
```

**EDIT**
I just tried your code and I can make the LeasClass to work as follow

```
<?php
namespace Pack\sp;
require_once("OtherFunctions.php");
require_once("SubClass.php");
class LeadClass {
  public function __construct($Name) {
    echo("_._");
    $NewSC = new SubClass();
    $NewSC->CArg = $Name;
    SetTble($Name);
    echo("ini:".GetTble().":end");
  }
}

$LeadClass = new LeadClass('table');

?>
```

Have you already initialize the class?

Comment: I want to use OtherFunctions.php different to Class... Because is a Script of only functions without related to class.

Comment: Sorry it was lo late yesterday, I just edited my answer, hope is useful